# CSRF token in a Cookie

Tags: cookies, csrf

What are the general recommendations regarding CSRF token.

Is it safe to have a csrf token inside a cookie?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSRF: Can I use a cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463422/csrf-can-i-use-a-cookie)